# Notification e-mail after successful FTP file transfer or file deletion

Tags: php, ftp, file-transfer, email-notifications

I'd like to send a notification e-mail each time a file was successfully transferred to or deleted from a specific folder via FTP (FileZilla). How do I realize that? As the files aren't transferred via PHP, the function *is_uploaded_file* seems to be not an option, does it?

Comment: do you want to send the email from filezella or from your server?

Comment: From the server via PHP function *mail*.

Comment: how about a cronjob checking the directory every 10 minutes

Comment: @Dagon: With *scandir* and *array_diff*? But how to distinguish if a file is transferred completely?

Comment: @hek2mgl: Linux. But I don't have shell access.

Comment: @Ben Ok. Then you are searching for a php solution. Note with (just) PHP and without shell access, I see no reliable solution. Normally one would use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) for that. A more or less the same mechanism of directory watching is possible on Windows (don't know api name, but having once done)

Comment: maybe you should switch to doing it with php

Comment: You could execute the check for changes in the FTP folder on each request, yes. But if there are no requests, we have a problem. Possible solution would be to trigger the request periodically from another machine. Then the frequency would be regulary once per minute. If this is ok for you it might be your solution. But it's really hacky and fragile ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to compare directory state, or hashing for fun and profit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343868/fastest-way-to-compare-directory-state-or-hashing-for-fun-and-profit)